# Cannot destructure property 'picture' of 'profileData' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to destructure my ProfileData variable that holds an object.  But, I have a problem to display the API data, so when it passes, my page breaks and sends me this error "Cannot destructure property 'picture' of 'profileData' as it is undefined.".I don't know the reason of the error message is the absence of the key "last_paper" in some objects but I don't know how to avoid this problem.
I don't know where the problem is and I don't know how to avoid this problem.

```
function Profile() {
   const { id: queryId } = useParams();
   const [profileData, setProfileData] = useState({});
   useEffect(() => {
      fetch(`http://localhost:8000/freelance?id=${queryId}`)
         .then((response) => response.json())
         .then((jsonResponse) => {
            setProfileData(jsonResponse?.freelaneData);
         });
   }, [queryId]);

   const { picture, name, location, tjm, job, skills, available, id } = profileData;
```

Comment: Do you expect that `profileData` holds the data you set with `setProfileData`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `freelaneData` is not present in all responses.

Either normalise your database response to include an empty object anyhow, or fallback to an empty object like:

```js
setProfileData(jsonResponse?.freelaneData || {});
```

Comment: It probably might be better to check if `profileData` is undefined instead of shadowing that `freelaneData` does not exists.

Comment: I just fixed the problem I had misspelled freelaneData instead of freelanceData. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your site to **crash** when **profileData** is **undefined** .
Just follow the below code :

```
function Profile() {
   const { id: queryId } = useParams();
   const [profileData, setProfileData] = useState({});
   useEffect(() => {
      fetch(`http://localhost:8000/freelance?id=${queryId}`)
         .then((response) => response.json())
         .then((jsonResponse) => {
            setProfileData(jsonResponse?.freelaneData);
         });
   }, [queryId]);

   const { picture, name, location, tjm, job, skills, available, id } = profileData || {};
```

In this case , picture , name or other **properties** which we are trying to **de structure** will be **undefined** .

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the problem I had misspelled freelaneData instead of freelanceData. Thank you for your help.

```
function Profile() {
   const { id: queryId } = useParams();
   const [profileData, setProfileData] = useState({});
   useEffect(() => {
      fetch(`http://localhost:8000/freelance?id=${queryId}`)
         .then((response) => response.json())
         .then((jsonResponse) => {
            setProfileData(jsonResponse?.freelanceData);
         });
   }, [queryId]);

   const { picture, name, location, tjm, job, skills, available, id } =
      profileData;
```